# How can I make an adaptable list of images in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am working on a Javascript, HTML, CSS and Google maps project.
For now, I only have the map and a button which opens a box with a list of images.

```
.report-img {
  margin: 20px;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
}

.report-box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.listImage {
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.listText {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 60px;
}
```

This is my list.

```
<img
        id="report-img"
        class="report-img"
        src="pictures/64/sea.png"
        onclick="openReportBox()"
      />
      <div id="report-box" class="report-box" style="display: none">
        <ul id="variableTable" style="display: block">
          <li>
            <img
              id="dirtywater"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
              width="64"
              height="64"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua sucia</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="group"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/group.png"
              width="64"
              height="64"
            />
            <p class="listText">Gente</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="jellyfish"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/jellyfish.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua-vivas</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="waves"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/waves.png"
              width="64"
              height="64"
            />
            <p class="listText">Olas</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="wind"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/windy.png"
              width="64"
              height="64"
            />
            <p class="listText">viento</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

I want to make this scale to the size of the screen but whatever I try is useless. I always end up with something like this which is not what I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GlTS.jpg

I ve seen a lot of tutorials and a lot of stackoverflow posts but I could not manage myself to achieve what I want. Any suggestion?

Comment: I have no idea what that image is showcasing. Can you please post a minimal example so we can help you, this isn't a lot of information to go off of.

Comment: @zfrisch Thanks for response. You can enter the link I posted and make zoom to see each image

Comment: I appreciate that you're new, so no offense at all, but you're not going to get help that way. You need to post all your relevant information inside of your question.

Comment: Thanks once again. I edit the post and give more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use onclick event `document.getElementById("your_id").style.backgroundSize="cover"`or`set width=100% height=100% position:center`if you want onClick event else  simply right `background-size="cover"` in the css of your element if you want it by default.